convert integer data stored as a character data to integer
I have a dataset with ages of individuals (range: 0-12) that are stored as characters. If I simply try to set this variable as an integer (using as.integer), I get an integer field, but the values are not correct. For example, the value 7 stored as a character, becomes a value of 3 stored as an integer. How do I get this data to not change values (i.e., the 7 should be a 7 regardless of whether it is a character or an integer)?

Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your dataset and code?

Also, have you tried using as.numeric()?

See the dup for complete description. The ?factor help page recommends using as.numeric(levels(f))[f] to turn factors into numbers based on their names.
